# Missing auto-complete for matplotlib in python 3 in pycharm (but for python 2.7 it works)

Tags: matplotlib, autocomplete, pycharm, python-3.6

I have a strange problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

then, typing `fig.` there is no auto-complete popping up. Same for other modules like `axes`.

I am using pycharm. I am using python 3.6 on windows. For python 2.7 the auto-complete works.

Comment: It caused by the recent `matplotlib` version which supports only Python 3. I created a ticket in PyCharm bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35981

Comment: Can I manually typehint or add a docstring in my script to let pycharm know that an `fig` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has annoyed me long enough. Apparently I am the only one using matplotlib in python 3 and pycharm who is too stupid to remember all methods of `Figure` and `Axes`.

But if I am not the only one, here is a workaround. Define your own function, write a proper docstring. For example:

```
def subplots(*args, **kwargs):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    args
    kwargs

    Returns
    -------
    f       :   matplotlib.figure.Figure
    ax      :   matplotlib.axes.Axes
    """
    f, ax = plt.subplots(*args, **kwargs)
    return f, ax
```

pycharm understands what `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is, so here you go.